# GeSHi Syntax Highlighting in Mediawiki for command line

Tags: console, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, geshi

Does the Mediawiki extension [SyntaxHighlight GeSHi](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi) come with highlighting support for bash/ash/sh, for example by coloring program arguments, strings and numbers or emphasizing commands? Example (this is SO highlighting for bash):

```bash
user@host ~/test $ ls "abc"
abc
```

Or is there some (generic) language definition which covers some of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
<syntaxhighlight lang="bash">
user@host ~/test $ ls "abc"
abc
</syntaxhighlight>
```

[gives](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Project:Sandbox&oldid=1912917):

```
<pre>
user@host ~/test <span class="nv">$ </span>ls <span class="s2">"abc"</span>
abc
</pre>
```

[image: Current display of the above output in my browser]

Note that the highlighter changed in recent versions of the extension.